# Linux based OS with static libraries: what can I do?

Tags: c++, c, linux, static-libraries

I have a linux based OS with a lot of system libraries compiled as static libraries.

How can I use such libraries in my application, and *link* them to my final binary?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see the problem. What where you trying to do?

Comment: @larsmans i have only worked with dynamic libraries since now, if you can explain yourself it will be probably good

Comment: In terms of the gcc linker options, you don't need to do anything different. When you tell it to link, it looks for a dynamic library, if not for a static library (lib*.a)

Comment: Have you tried just compiling and linking Hello World? If the headers are there, everything should be fine. Only some plug-in architectures will not work without shared libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use them as you do use shared libraries, except that you link against statically. [An introduction to GCC - shared libraries and static libraries](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html) article will get you started.

Comment: i need an exact copy of the library or only the same symbols ? Because what matters in the dynamic linking are symbols and not whole library.

Comment: @axis: a static library is an archive of object files. You need the whole library. Pulling off the trick with dynamic loading/linking is not possible in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I've trouble to understand. If you are linking with something like

```
g++ -o myprog myprog.o obj1.o obj2.o -L/path/to/lib -L/path2/to/lib -llib1 -llib2 -lib3
```

the linker called through the gcc or g++ wrapper will do "the right thing(tm)", if liblib1.so exist in the library path (/path/to/lib, /path2/to/lib plus a set of system specific directories where system libraries probably are), it will be linked dynamically, if not liblib1.a will be linked statically.  The only thing to be aware of, is that if there are mutual dependencies in static libaries (lib1 needs lib2 and lib2 needs lib1), you may need to repeat them several times or use the `--start-group` and `--end-group` options of ld to mark libraries which needs to be considered together.

Comment: this libraries are not standard and the machines where i develop and where i'm supposed to deploy stuff are different.

Comment: Static libraries mean that the (needed part of the) content of the archive is copied in the executable. You don't need to deploy static libraries.

Comment: yes, but i need them on my working machine, so i need a copy of the whole targeted OS in my case, which is something that i would like to avoid for several reasons ... i was talking about the other way, i get that part

Comment: To link with a static library, you need it (just as you need the header files which provides the declarations for the library when compiling -- even if your system is similar enough to provide headers by the same name which may seem to work, some details may be off and would lead to issues that I wouldn't want to track).